# NodeJS :: TypeError: Cannot call method 'query' of undefined

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

Can some one please help me with this. I have been searching all over and Cannot get a clear solution.

#### database.js

```
var MySql           = require('mysql');
var moment          = require('moment');

var connection = MySql.createConnection({
   host         : dbHost,
   user         : Username,
   password     : MysQlPassword,
   database     : dbName
});

connection.connect( function( err){
    if (err) {
        console.log( "There was a problem " + err );
    } else {
        console.log( "Database Connection successful,");
    }
});
```

On my Products page route I have the following, I will have other methods on here for creating, update, delete and get single products

#### product.js

```
var dbConnect = require('../config/database');

var products = {
 create: function(req, res) {},

 getAll: function(req, res){

  var data = dbConnect.connection.query("SELECT * FROM products ", function( err, result){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
   });
 var allProducts = data;
 res.json(allProducts);

 }


};

module.exports = products;
```

And on the console I have the following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'query' of undefined
at products.getAll (/home/anele/Desktop/myApp/server/routes/products.js:8:37)
```

Comment: You're not exporting `connection`. `exports.connection = connection`.

Comment: Thanks @BenFortune. That worked. Do u know about TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
Since I am using MySql. I only see a solution for using Mongoose

Answer (score 0):

#### ANSWER

As per [@ben-fortune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2615209/ben-fortune)

```
var MySql    = require('mysql'),
    moment   = require('moment');

var connection = MySql.createConnection({
    host         : dbHost,
    user         : Username,
    password     : MysQlPassword,
    database     : dbName
});

connection.connect( function( err){
   if (err) {
     console.log( "There was a problem " + err );
   } else {
    console.log( "Database Connection successful,");
   }
});

// I was missing the code bellow
module.exports = connection;
```